# Git access denied on different PC?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

So i downloaded git for windows and created a key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my@email.com"
```

And pasted the generated key in `c:\users\myname\.ssh` into my project/repository on gitlab. But I cannot seem to access my repository. When i want to push I first get the `Permanently added warning to the list of unknown hosts`. Then `access denied` and `could not read from remote repository`.

I just setup my account at home for the first time a view days ago and i cannot seem to figure out what i'm doing differently. What does the warning exactly mean? Does it even find the SSH key on my new system? I tried creating/attaching a key multiple times, even without a passphrase.

I have gone through these docs several times without results: https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\ecosense [master]> ssh -vT madmenyo@github.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 5: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.130] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mgw/.ssh/github_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mgw/.ssh/github_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.6.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.6.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.130' (RSA) to the list of know
n hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: C:\\Users\\mgw\\.ssh\\github_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/mgw/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/mgw/.ssh/github_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

This might be relevant since it is different then the troubleshooting doc. I have two addresses here:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\ecosense [master]> ssh-add -l
2048 90:1b:b7:a4:22:29:82:a9:c1:17:37:b6:19:e9:d9:a2 C:\Users\mgw\.ssh\github_rs
a (RSA)
2048 8e:59:95:d2:33:3f:08:c2:56:66:79:4b:00:2d:31:42 /c/Users/mgw/.ssh/id_rsa (R
SA)
```

Comment: Did you paste private or public key? :)

Comment: I got 2 files, i took the one with the key in 1 line. It might be the .pub file. Coult it be the priblem? At home i got 4 ssh files.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes i pasted the .pub key into my repository. I cannot paste the other one: key is invalid, fingerprint could not be taken. I did try to remove all the line breaks and pasting just the encode string.